# How is it possible to change the color by clicking on Canvas circles (3 pieces) with the same mouse button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

What if else structure should I create so that when I click on any circle with the mouse, the recoloring will be executed?

```
import tkinter as tk

class CanvasEvents(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('510x510+700+100')
        self.title("Event")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='grey', width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack(pady=5)

        kor1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 20, 100, 100, width=2, fill="orange")
        kor2 = self.canvas.create_oval(220, 20, 300, 100, width=2, fill="red")
        kor3 = self.canvas.create_oval(420, 20, 500, 100, width=2, fill="green")

        self.canvas.tag_bind(kor1, '<Button-1>', self.object_click_event)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(kor2, '<Button-1>', self.object_click_event)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(kor3, '<Button-1>', self.object_click_event)

    def object_click_event(self, event):
        # if else ??????????????????
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(event.num, fill="blue")
        print('Clicked object at: ', self.canvas.coords(event.num), event.num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ablak = CanvasEvents()
    ablak.mainloop()
```

I tried setting if else conditions, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the special tag "current" which is defined as "it applies to the current item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor"

```
def object_click_event(self, event):
    self.canvas.itemconfigure('current', fill="blue")
```